# Lua:Stack in dll library when 2 functions are in use

Tags: dll, lua, stack

There are two functions in my dll-library. Both are frequently used by Lua script (up to 1000 times per second). 
My question is about stack.
Are there any risks that they will mistakenly take elements of each other? First function works in first thread, second works in another thread. I am afraid there will be confusion when they both will use stack. Their stacks are different or they use the same stack?

Comment: Which kind of "stack" are we talking about? The C/C++ stack, or the Lua stack? If it's the latter, then are you sharing the same Lua state between the two threads?

Comment: Lua script works with dll library written on C++.  I call dll functions from Lua script. They work with each other using stack. for i=1,iterations do s=runfast.SumArray(t) end ///// SumArray(t) is function inside dll called runfast.